# Concat multiple variables and strings in ansible playbook

Tags: ansible, concatenation, yaml

I'm trying multiple concatenation when preforming `with_items` for the destination section.

Right now it looks like this:

```
- name: create app except+lookup
  copy: content="" dest="{{ dir.comp ~ '/config/con2dd/' ~ item.name ~ 'File.txt' }}" force=no group=devops owner=devops mode: 0755
  with_items:
...
```

I get:

```
We could be wrong, but this one looks like it might be an issue with
missing quotes.  Always quote template expression brackets when they 
start a value. For instance:            

    with_items:
      - {{ foo }}

Should be written as:

    with_items:
      - "{{ foo }}"
```

Tried couple of approaches but none resulted something that's working.

Is it possible to concat the variables with the strings?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Don't mix pure YAML and key=value syntaxes for parameters. And always use YAML syntax for complex arguments:

```
- name: create app except+lookup
  copy:
    content: ""
    dest: "{{ dir.comp }}/config/con2dd/{{ item.name }}File.txt"
    force: no
    group: devops
    owner: devops
    mode: 0755
  with_items:
  ...
```

Comment: ended up using this tough both are correct. Thanks :)

Answer (score 3):

You are not quoting the value associated with the key `copy`. For that to happen the **first** character has to be double (or single) quote. The example, given in the feedback, does this correctly, but is not explicit about it. Once a scalar start with a non-quote (yours start with the `c` from `content` quotes occurring in the scalar will no longer have a special meaning.

Because of a bug in the parser that Ansible uses, the `:` (colon space) in that scalar (`mode: 0755`) causes trouble, you should double quote the whole scalar and escape the double quotes that occur within it:

```
copy: "content=\"\" dest=\"{{ dir.comp ~ '/config/con2dd/' ~ item.name ~ 'File.txt' }}\" force=no group=devops owner=devops mode: 0755"
```

or alternatively use single quotes (which have different escape rules:

```
copy: 'content="" dest="{{ dir.comp ~ ''/config/con2dd/'' ~ item.name ~ ''File.txt'' }}" force=no group=devops owner=devops mode: 0755'
```

You can test scalars yourself on [this](http://yaml-online-parser.appspot.com/) online YAML parser, it has the same bug as what causes Ansible not to parse your YAML correctly.

[This](https://nimyaml.org/testing.html) parser, handles the in scalar `:` correctly and will not produce an error with your input (but it has other problems).